# Cloud Functions embedded web editor display weirds characters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am working from a remote laptop so I am using the web editor embedded in Cloud Function (when you go to your function's details, then in "Source").

Everything worked well until today, the file **index.js** (other files don't) show me this :

[image: Image of characters shown in the web editor]

I have an other function and I have no problem with it, it's only this one.
I tried to replace the whole code of the file by the good version but when I deploy it gets messed up again. I also tried to delete the function and to recreate it but same thing.

Edit: added details

Edit 2: I added a few lines of code in the file, redeployed it and the issue disappeared but came back when I modified the code again.

Comment: Have you also tried other Nodejs runtimes if this issue will still persist?

Comment: @RobertG I just tried with 16 and 20 and I still have the issue

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to deploy some sample projects for Cloud Functions using different [Node.js runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-runtime) and I haven't encountered any issues. No issues were also present through the [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/).

I would suggest filing this one as a bug through the [Google Cloud Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) so that Google Cloud engineers could take a deeper look at this and provide further resolution regarding this matter.

There's no specific ETA for this but you can keep track of its progress once the ticket has been created.

Comment: I will open an issue, thank you for the advice.